# Having problems setting up button of another layout

Tags: android

The problem is MainActivity starts with a setContentView with a layout.xml. We can add buttons or anything to the layout and code in in the MainActivity class but when I try to code the buttons of another layout in the same Activity the app forces stop . Whats wrong ?

Ok I found out that is because of the context.
When you try to change other activity you have to use layoutinflater. Example below

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View myLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);
```

To work with widgets inside it like buttons or anything .

```
Button b = mylayout.findViewById(R.id.button);

b.setText("Successfully changed");
```

Now you can use myLayout as your changed layout.

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: Post your stack trace.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please sent me your Activities
What the text of problem ?

You may write next code to go to another activity

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),nameActivity.class));
            }
        });
```

Where button is name of your button

See that you xml-file doesnt have any mistakes

Comment: Yes bro going to another activity is fine . I am talking about coding buttons from another layout in the same activity.

Comment: What the text of problem ?

Comment: I can't help you if you dont sent me a text of problem

Comment: See that you xml-file doesnt have any mistakes and dont forgot about Manifest file

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a crash because you are trying to access the layout when it is not inflated. In other words, you must call `setContentView()` on an Activity, or `inflater.inflate()` on a Fragment to instantiate the view and make the elements accessible for manipulation. So if you want to add buttons to another Activity, you would need to call its `onCreate()` and `setContentView()` before you can add buttons to it.

**EDIT: In response to comments...**

In order to access/manipulate/modify elements in a layout at runtime, they must first be instantiated, which happens when the view is inflated. So to add a button to an Activity at runtime, you would do it in the `onCreate()` method after calling `setContentView()` like this:

Keep in mind this is the `onCreate()` of your SECOND activity...not your main Activity. So your main activity would start this Activity, then the button would get created during the setup of the second Activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_second_activity;

    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setText("Your New Button");

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("NEW BUTTON", "I just clicked my new button!");
        }
    });

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_in_your_second_activity);
    relativeLayout.addView(button);
}
```

If you are using a Fragment to display your UI, you can't access your UI elements until you have inflated your layout, which happens in the `onCreateView()` method. So you would do something like this in your Fragment code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout, container, false);
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.container_layout_that_holds_button);

    //You would get your context from an onAttach() Override
    Button button = new Button(context);
    button.setText("Your New Button");
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("NEW BUTTON", "I just clicked my new button!");
        }
    });

    relativeLayout.addView(button);

    return view;
}
```

You're likely getting a `NullPointerException` when you try to manipulate your layouts before they are created. Keep in mind that even if you have an XML file with layouts specified within, the actual objects for those elements won't be created until the system decides it needs them, which happens when you actually try to display the view.

Comment: Can you kindly give an example what to do ?